# afterPlaceOrder function is not redirecting to external link for custom payment gateway

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, payment

[image]I added the code for afterPlaceOrder function in sample payment .js file,but it is not been redirected to external link.When I click on Place Order button,success page is been displayed(default functionality),whereas it should be redirected to external link.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your url is not correct.

app/code/Magento\SamplePaymentGateway/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="magentocommunity" frontName="magentocommunity">
            <module name="Magento_SamplePaymentGateway"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Now your url should be:

> magentocommunity/checkout/index

**Clear cache.**

Comment: Thanks for the help.